# How to alphabetical book title using query

Tags: mysql

I want to alphabetical a-Z using query and this is my code

```
select * from book WHERE book_title REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z]'
```

But didn't worked.

database table:
[image: database table]

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it more clear what you want? It's not easy to see what the goal here is. The question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use order by for alphabetical order-

```
SELECT * FROM `book` ORDER BY book.book_title ASC
```